# SerializeJSON returning empty object

Tags: javascript, json

I am using `serializeJSON()` to capture my form data, but my object is returning empty for some reason.

My form:

```
    <form id="addreport">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="projectId">Project ID</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="projectId" value="{{projectId}}" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="startDate">Iteration Start</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="startDate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="endDate">Iteration End</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" id="endDate" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy">
        </div>
         <button type="" id="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

My JS file:

```
var formData = $("#addreport").serializeJSON();
console.log(formData); //returns Object {}
```

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: where does `serializeJSON()` come from?s sounds made-up to me...

Comment: it's this library https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON ; i included a reference to the library in my code as well

Comment: it wants `name` instead of `id` attribs on the inputs to name the JSON object keys. https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON/blob/master/jquery.serializejson.js#L37

Comment: works now, thanks! oddly, it used to work before even with `id` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have "name" properties in your inputs